# Is there an editor to autoindent / add spaces in existing code?

Tags: indentation, reformat

I have some JavaScript code which I want to make more readable. However, due to the amount of code I want to use a tool which does this automatically for me.

- Are there such tools already available or do I have to manually perform some "find/replace-alls"?

The code which I want to convert is written on a single line without spaces.

Comment: Visual Studio at least adds the spaces, but does not perform the line split

Comment: -1 for [minimal effort fail](http://bit.ly/123gHM6)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick search found http://jsbeautifier.org/ which seems to do what you are looking for online.
Search terms: javascript beautifier

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what I've looked for.